# Feeding pairwise compared values into a large table

Tags: excel

I've got a few large (500-1000) datasets in the following format using only the first two rows.

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| a-b | number |
| a-c | number |
| a-d | number |
| ... | number |
| b-c | number |
| b-d | number |

and so on

They compare two values and save their difference while skipping previously done comparisons. I want to put them in a table like this:

| id | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | / | number | number | number | number |
| b | number | / | number | number | number |
| c | number | number | / | number | number |
| d | number | number | number | / | number |
| e | number | number | number | number | / |

The lower left half of this table is easily prepared with offset, but how do I feed the values into the upper right half?
Is there a way to mostly automate doing this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, just noticed the first table broke!

Comment: A few questions: 1) are you looking for the solution to be formula based or VBA? 2) in your data, you exclude(?) `a-a`, `b-b` but not `c-c`, `d-d`, `e-e` - typo or something subtle? 3) `The lower left half of this table is easily prepared with offset, but how do I feed the values into the upper right half?` can you share what you have done so far?  4) `They compare two values and save their difference while skipping previously done comparisons` so you have some sparse data, you fill in the table with what you have and then there is another "pass" so that over time you fill in the blanks?

Comment: Hi there: 1) If possible formula based. 2) That was a typo, yes. It should be fixed now. 3) The idea is to write the compared date into the cells to the top and right of the / characters and then use a simple Offset command pasted across the 'lower half' to copy the values from up above, because the values for cell ba should be the same for ab. 4) I'm not sure if my answer to #3 is what you meant with this.

Comment: So you want the data reflected across the diagonal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand what you are trying to do, I would suggest to do this in 2 steps:

1. Set up formulas in the results table to "read" data
2. Have a macro to "save" data

First fill your results table with this formula (example for cell `B2`) - keep your `offset` formula in bottm left half

```
=IF(B$2=$A3, "\", VLOOKUP(IF(B$2>$A3,$A3&"-"&B$2, B$2&"-"&$A3), $H$3:$I$35, 2, FALSE))
```

This will give you `\` if the row and column id or the same or `vlookup` on `row_id-column_id`/`column_id-row_id` if they are different ensuring they are ordered "low-high" always to give you your mirror across the diagonal. Some might argue the duplication of `vlookup` is inefficient but more inefficient than an `offset` and figuring our how to paste one formula into one diagonal and a different one in the other? Who really knows and it is simple and it works IMHO

[image]

Next put the data for the current "pass" into the observations table and your values will appear in the table via the `VLOOKUP`

[image]
Finally you need a little macro to replace the formula with the value and run it after every set of results is acquired, so that you don't lose this data when you put a subsequent set of new values in your results table

```
Option Explicit

Sub replace_formula_with_value()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  
  Dim r_in As Range
  
  ' this is where my input data start
  Set r_in = Range(ws.Range("B3"), ws.Range("B3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
  
  Dim r As Range
  For Each r In r_in
    If Not IsError(r.Value) Then
      If r.Value <> "\" Then
        'overwrite formula with value by setting value to the evaluation of the formula in the cell
        r.Value = r.Value
      End If
    End If
  Next r
  

End Sub
```

If you dont want to have a macro then you need to keep ***ALL*** data in your observations table and just build it up over time.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is going to save me quite the hassle. If you'll allow me one last question: How do I now quickly go about replacing the lower (or upper part, doesn't matter, really!) with the 'mirroring' offset formula? Copying seems to be a pain when diagonals are involved.

Comment: Seems to be working flawlessly. Thanks again. If any issues do come up I know which Excel wizard to ask.